# No power in my outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have two outlets that seems to be having this same issue within a room. The other outlets in the room work fine. The outlets are reading 11.2 volts on the multimeter instead of 120. Is there a wire issue or should I replace the outlet? [image]

Comment: What is the voltage between hot and ground, and between neutral and ground?

Comment: Neutral to ground is 0, hot to ground 8.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at the last working outlet, pull the outlet out, after turning off the power, and check the connections, If the backstabs are used, remove them and use the screw terminals with a shepherd's hook on the wires. Then work your way down doing the same to the remaining outlets